# How to store 10 numbers (updated weekly) with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

My GAE app will request weekly data from Google Analytics like

- number of visitors during last week
- number of visitors of particular page during last week
- etc.

Then I would like to show this data on my GAE web-page with [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/). The data will be shown for last X weeks (let's say, 10 weeks).

What is the best approach to store this data (number of metrics multiplied by number of weeks)? Old data could be deleted.

I don't think I should use datastore like:

```
class Visitors(ndb.Model):
    week1 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0) # should store week start and end dates also
    week2 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    ...
```

Probably, it would be better to store data like:

```
class Analytics(ndb.Model):
    visitors = ndb.StringProperty(default=0) # comma separated values like '1000,1001,1002'; last value is previous week
    page_visitors = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True,default=0) # [1000,1001,1002]
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to optimize?

With this amount of data, you will pay pennies, or less, for data storage. You are well within the free quota on datastore reads and writes. Performance-wise, the difference is negligible.

I would recommend going with the most straightforward solution: each week is a new entity, each data point is in its own property.

Comment: This is just about overall optimization. If I follow your approach, then how should I read last 10 entities?

Comment: Order entities by date (descending), and set a limit to retrieve 10 entities in your query.